# detect dolby atmos audio/video from meta data

Tags: mediainfo, dolby

I'm using mediainfo to extract metadata from audio and video files. I need to find whether the file supports dolby atmos. What are the properties on the meta data that I can use to detect the dolby atmos supported audio or video files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the graphical interface or command line interface, check the `Commercial name` line, it contains "Atmos" if Atmos is detected.
Programmaticaly, get the `Format_Commercial` field:

```
MediaInfo::Get(Stream_Audio, 0, "Format_Commercial");
```

And check if it contains `Atmos`.